# Magento - Previous and Next product links in product page (check product status)

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have implemented "Prev / Next" buttons in product view (view.phtml) and it is working fine. Only problem is that it is also trying to show product with status: "Disabled". This results in 404 Not found page.

Any workaround/fix for this?
This is my code:

```
<?php // Previous and Next product links in product page
$_product = $this->getProduct();
if (!$_product->getCategoryIds())
    return; // Don't show Previous and Next if product is not in any category

$cat_ids           = $_product->getCategoryIds(); // get all categories where the product is located
$cat               = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_ids[0]); // load first category,     you should enhance this, it works for me
$order             = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/default_sort_by');
$direction         = 'asc'; // asc or desc

$category_products = $cat->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort($order, $direction);
$category_products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); // 1 or 2
$category_products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); // 1.2.3.4

$cat_prod_ids = $category_products->getAllIds(); // get all products from the category
$_product_id  = $_product->getId();
$_pos         = array_search($_product_id, $cat_prod_ids); // get position of current product
$_next_pos    = $_pos + 1;
$_prev_pos    = $_pos - 1;

// get the next product url
if (isset($cat_prod_ids[$_next_pos])) {
    $_next_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($cat_prod_ids[$_next_pos]);
} else {
    $_next_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(reset($cat_prod_ids));
}

// get the previous product url
if (isset($cat_prod_ids[$_prev_pos])) {
    $_prev_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($cat_prod_ids[$_prev_pos]);
} else {
    $_prev_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(end($cat_prod_ids));
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: please use this code for previous next product on view page. http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/previousnext-product-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

ENABLE the product.

Disabled products cannot be displayed in frontend.